# Help me on getiing the url string

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

what is the method to get the url from the NSURLConnection *theConnection object.

i mean i want to check like below

> // did receive response
>   - ( void )connection:( NSURLConnection * )connection didReceiveResponse:( NSURLResponse * )response 
>   //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {  if ( connection == @"http://google.com" ) 
>     {   }   else 
>   {   }
>
> }

Is that possible...pls help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude the url is not stored in the connection, it's stored in the NSURLResponse object.

```
if (response.url isEqual: ...) // you can get what you want here, the return value is a (NSURL *)
```